# How to fetch a particular value from a repeating node

Tags: xslt

Folks:
Kindly excuse on this newbie question, but please do help me out -

I'm using XSL to manipulate some values within an XML which looks as below -

```
<userFields>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST1</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>123</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST2</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>999</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST3</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>756</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST4</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>1234</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
...
</userFields>
```

I need to get the FieldVal for a specific "FieldName", say I need the FieldVal for FieldName "TEST2" (in this case which is 999), how do I accomplish this please?
Intent is to store the value in a variable and add it as a seperate user field within the XML, so the result looks like this -

```
<userFields>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST1</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>123</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST2</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>999</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST3</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>756</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
<userField>
   <FieldName>TEST4</FieldName>
   <FieldVal>1234</FieldVal>
   <Fieldtype>char</Fieldtype>
</userField>
...
</userFields>
<variableX>999</variableX>
```

I would like to store the Fieldval of TEST2 in a variableX within the XML. this is so cause I can pass this variable as an argument for a subsequent db fetch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is this..

```
<xsl:variable name="field" select="//userField[FieldName='TEST2']/FieldVal" />
```

Alternatively, define a key to lookup the elements..

```
<xsl:key name="userFields" match="userField" use="FieldName" />
```

Then you can do the look-up like so...

```
<xsl:variable name="field" select="key('userFields', 'TEST2')/FieldVal" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="userFields" match="userField" use="FieldName" />
  <xsl:param name="fieldName" select="'TEST4'" />

    <xsl:variable name="field" select="key('userFields', $fieldName)/FieldVal" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="userFields">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <variableX>
       <xsl:value-of select="$field" />
    </variableX>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have made the "TEST2" a parameter so it could be passed in by the main application.

Also note the use of the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy existing values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. However if i tweak the requirement a bit and wanted to assign the value to the variable chosenval? Would it be something like this -

Comment: It may be better to edit your question with your "tweaked" requirement. Thanks!

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how you can store the result in a variable

Comment: Thank you Tim, both answers helped me learn something new. You are a star.